# What kind of pepper is this and when will it be "ripe"?

Tags: identification, peppers, ripening, habaneros

What kind of pepper is this and when will it be "ripe"?

The peppers are a bit larger than a cherry tomato (maybe apricot size).

[image: pepper plant with small peppers]

**UPDATE**: The peppers turn red after they ripen.

Comment: They will likely turn red or orange - depending on the strain - that's the sign of ripeness.

Comment: @tim you called it! they turned bright red.

Comment: Enjoy.  I used to make hot sauce from it - fairly easy to do.  Lots of fun.  And you can enjoy it the rest of the year...

Comment: @Tim they are actually perfect.  One pepper in dinner makes the whole thing hot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think they might be scotch bonnet habaneros.

[image: scotch bonnet pepper from flickr sassyradish]

UPDATE: Tried one. Super hot. Definitely habanero.

Comment: interesting thought - I see your C.chinensis leaves look like C.annuum - I assumed they would be smaller (as with the other spieces of Capsicum) - I've never grown c.Chinensis. it should be easy for the OP to tell them apart by taste (C.chinensis is very hot).

Comment: Some Habaneros for sure. Maybe scotch bonnet, but that's hard to say from one picture of unripe fruit.

Answer (score 7):

Peppers easily hybridize so it is possible you may never know, or it might be an obscure variety (My supplier lists 100 or so).

It looks like it is almost certainly a cultivar of *Capiscum annuum* (as are most cultivated chile peppers).

The closest match to anything I've grown would be **Gypsy**. This is a small yellow bell pepper that likes warm climates. Size and colour are a good match although they are not as spherical and nobly.

As to when it is ripe? Watch the colours - let a pepper ripen without picking and see where it ends up. You can eat it at any time - remember that green bell peppers and jalapeños are simply unripe peppers! As it ripens, peppers will tend to become sweeter. With yellow peppers, they tend to turn from a green/yellow to a purer yellow. The gypsies turn into more of a lemon yellow shade.